# Can somebody recognize this encryptiom algorithm?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, encryption, reverse-engineering

i found this encryption algorithm by decompiling an Android App (probably left over from an obfuscator) that gets called whenever there is a string, but i can't figure out what it is.

I've recreated the algorithm in Python, so here's an example:

```py
def decodeStr(input: str, intCode: int, charSecCode: str, mode: int) -> str:
    outString = ""
    for charIndex in range(len(input)):
        inputCurrChar = ord(input[charIndex]) & 65535
        
        if mode == 3:
            code = inputCurrChar - (intCode + charIndex) - ord(charSecCode)
        elif mode == 0:
            code = (inputCurrChar - (intCode + charIndex)) + ord(charSecCode)
        else:
            code = inputCurrChar - (intCode * 3) + ord(charSecCode)

        if code < 0:
            moduloCode = -(-code % 127)
        else:
            moduloCode = code % 127

        if moduloCode < 0:
            moduloCode += 127

        outString += chr(moduloCode)
    return outString
```

If i call this function with these parameters:

```
decodeStr("\nx\u0006\r\u0010\n\u0004", 233, '+', 3)
```

the output is going to be "samsung"

Comment: @Wonka Well, I guess the combination of `intCode` & `charSecCode` could be considered a key for a weak cipher. I don't think this cipher has a name though.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-onstrike surely this was made only to make the decompilation harder to read, not to secure any secrets

Comment: Yeah, probably. We normally call that "obfuscation" rather than encryption. This certainly is far from a cipher we consider secure, but since it does have a "key"...

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 3 distinct ciphers depending on the `mode`.

- When `mode` is 0 or 3, these are polyalphabetic substitution ciphers, where the alphabets are all rotations of the base alphabet.  The only difference between the two is the starting point for the rotations; i.e. `+charSecCode` versus `-charSecCode`.
- For other `mode` values, it is a simple substitution cipher; i.e. there is only one alphabet.

---

> surely this was made only to make the decompilation harder to read, not to secure any secrets

That is a reasonable assumption.

In all cases the cipher is weak / easy to crack if you have enough ciphertext.  If `intCode`, `charSecCode`, and `mode` vary and / or there is insufficient ciphertext, cracking may be more difficult.